# XSLT with namespaces: Copy template omits attributes

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Applying the standard XSLT copy template,

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to the [JBoss AS 7 standalone.xml](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/blob/master/build/src/main/resources/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml), leads to loss of parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1">
    <extensions>
        <extension/>
        <extension/>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
```

Why?
How can i Make it copy everything?

XSLT transformation is done by Maven XML plugin.
The whole template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:ds="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0"
            xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1"
            version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*|@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, false alarm - there was another transformation going on elsewhere in the process with a screwed template.
I almost lost belief in almighty XSLT :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template appears to be working correctly.

I modified it and the XML to show that is working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1">
  <extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
  </extensions>
</server>
```

Run with this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ds="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0"
                xmlns:so="urn:jboss:domain:1.1"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*|@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="so:extension">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="testing">just for fun!!</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1">
  <extensions>
    <extension testing="just for fun!!" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension testing="just for fun!!" module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
  </extensions>
</server>
```

Here's the output run with your original XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1">
  <extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
  </extensions>
</server>
```

I downloaded the full JBoss standalone.xml, ran your XSL, and here's the diff of the input and output XML:

```
so zacharyyoung$ xsltproc so.xsl so.xml > output.xml
so zacharyyoung$ diff so.xml output.xml
1,2c1
< <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
< 
---
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Comment: Thanks for validating, it made me check the whole process and... see my comment on the question. Thanks!